# How to display the table correctly within the page width

Tags: tables, tabularx

I want to display the table within the page width without much space at the left, and minimizing the width of the 1st column

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}



\begin{table}[t]
    \begin{tabular}{|p|c|p|p{4cm}|}

    \hline
    
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}                      &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Big Title}}     \\ 
    \cline{3-4} 
    
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{}}    &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Second Title}           & 
    Third Title                                 \\ 
    \hline
    
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                      & 
    \textbf{Description (Part one)}             & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text}           & 
    values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text            \\ 
    \cline{2-4} 
    
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\makecell{A lot of description}}} & 
    \textbf{Description (Part Two)}             & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{values and text, values and text, values and text}                                                               & 
    values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text                             \\ 
    \hline
    
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Important characteristics}}                & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{FE0000} values and text, values and text, values and text}}                                      & 
    {\color[HTML]{009901} values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text}    \\ 
    
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about your requirements? What should wrap? Do you want the text in the third column *not* to wrap like that in the fourth column? All we have to go on here is how the table looks as is, and clearly by the laws of geometry, it can't stay the way it is and fit in the textwidth. What do you envision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution similar to Zarko's but using the `tabularray` package, which has a nice new interface making complex tables easier to work with. See [its documentation](https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf).

I've set the first two columns to different fixed widths (adjust as needed), and made the last two expandable, with coefficients (`co=3`/`co=5`) making the fourth 3/5th the size of the third, but again, adjust as needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text; to show it fits

\definecolor{myred}{HTML}{FE0000}
\definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{009901}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begin{table}[t]
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={Q[c,wd=1cm]Q[c,wd=2cm]% first two columns have fixed widths, centered
    X[c,co=5]X[l,co=3]},% third and forth columns expandable, fourth is 3/5ths the third and left-aligned
    rows = {font=\small},% use a smaller font (optional, but will fit better)
    width=\textwidth,% set width of table to that of text
    vlines,hlines% lines everywhere
}
%% first header row
\SetCell[c=2,r=2]{c} & &
\SetCell[c=2]{c} \textbf{Big Title} & \\
%% second header row
& & Second Title & Third title \\
%% first content row
\SetCell[r=2]{c}{A lot of description} &
\textbf{Description (Part one)} &
values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text
&
values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text
\\
% second content row
&
\textbf{Description (Part Two)} 
&
values and text, values and text, values and text
&
values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text
\\
% last content row
\SetCell[c=2]{c,wd=3cm} \textbf{Important characteristics} & &
\SetCell{fg=myred} values and text, values and text, values and text &
\SetCell{fg=mygreen} values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: reworked table]

Answer (score 2):

Your MWE has many errors:

- In column specification columns `p` must hafe defined column width.
- Using `multicolumn{1}{|c|{ {...}` in  columns of type `p` (or `X`, if `X` columns defined in the  `tabularx` is used overwrite column specification, consequently content of cell is in one (very long) line and table spill out of text block right border
- Your use of `makecell` has no sense, it can be omitted.
- `multirow` cells in your case should have specification `\multirow{...}{?}{ ... text ...}`. In this case width of cell will have the same width as specified in column specification

A possible solution, used `tabularx` package can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X
                                 |>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X
                                 |>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X
                                 |>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X|}

    \hline

    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}                      &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Big Title}}     \\
    \cline{3-4}

    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{}}    &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Second Title}           &
    Third Title                                 \\
    \hline

    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                      &
    \textbf{Description (Part one)}             &
    values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text           &
    values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text            \\
    \cline{2-4}

    \multirow{-2}{=}{A lot of descriptio} &
    \textbf{Description (Part Two)}             &
    values and text, values and text, values and text                                                              &
    values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text                             \\
    \hline

    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Important characteristics}}                &
    \color[HTML]{FE0000} values and text, values and text, values and text                                      &
    \color[HTML]{009901} values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text    \\

    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate borders of text block)

**Addendum:**
And one more version using `tabularray` package (tested by version 2022C). Quite similar to the @frabjous answer (+1), but with a slightly shorter code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[xcdraw]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = {X[0.6, l] X[0.8, l, font=\bfseries] *{2}{X[1.3, j]}},
                 row{1}  = {font=\bfseries},  
                 hspan = minimal}
%
\SetCell[c=2, r=2]{c}
    &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Big Title   
            &                   \\
    &   &   Second Title                    
            &   Third Title     \\
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    A lot of description
    &   Description (Part one)             
        &   values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text           
            &   values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text            
                                \\
    &   Description (Part Two)
        &   values and text, values and text, values and text
            &   values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text                             
                                \\
\SetCell[c=2]{c, font=\bfseries}   Important characteristics
    &   &   \SetCell{fg=red} values and text, values and text, values and text 
            &   \SetCell{fg=green}   values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text, values and text    \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]